# Passing a blob to lightning controller from controller?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, data

Is there a way to pass the contents of a large file(in this case a CSV file with upwards of 20,000 rows) to a lightning controller without running it through JSON.stringify, and ideally keeping it as a blob? Alternative, is there a way to simply write the contents of the blob file directly to an sObject?

Comment: Hi Stas, welcome to SFSE! Please take the time to visit the [Help] and read [How do I ask a good question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). If you post what you've written so far and where you're stuck, I'm confident you'll find plenty of people willing to assist you. For example, it's not clear where you're passing the file from and whether you're passing to the Component's Apex Controller, JS Controller and whether it's from an upload or between the two controllers, etc.

Comment: Why not just pass the `Blob.toString` result to the front end? No need to involve `JSON`.